# Does DockerInstaller task replace any existing installed Docker version?

Tags: docker, azure-pipelines

We're using the DockerInstaller task in our Azure Devops pipelines. What happens if a different version of Docker is already installed on the agent machine? Does it upgrade, downgrade, fail, or other? Is it possible that multiple Docker can exist side by side on the same agent machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated by OP：**

Confirmed that the task only affects the current pipeline run and not the entire machine.

---

Seems you are talking about this [DockerInstaller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/docker-installer?view=azure-devops) task, which is used to install a specific version of the Docker CLI on the agent machine.

After some tests, it should work.

[image]

But there are not too many supported versions in this task.

You could also choose to use scripts to handle the process, take a look at this answer: [multiple docker clients on the same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37617400/multiple-docker-clients-on-the-same-machine)

Comment: Thanks for the testing! The concern that I have is, what if two pipelines with two different DockerInstaller version settings run at the same time on two different agents on the same machine?

Comment: Ok, I spun up a test of my own. Confirmed that the task only affects the current pipeline run and not the entire machine.